# How do you get javascript promises to work with node + express and display on an EJS file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, asynchronous, ejs

Before saying to look at the docs, I have and they were not helpful in the slightest.

I have an web page with node as the backbone. On one page I need to request the past 10 images from NASA's Astronomy Picture of the Day (APOD) API and then after that, I need to request the next 5 upcoming launches from the Launch Library API (https://launchlibrary.net/docs/1.3/api.html). My problem is that not all the APODs will load (which I understand because of the nature of asynchronous requests).

Here is my concise app.js file for the Node backend:

```
app.get("/index", function(req, res) {
    /**Requesting NASA's Astronomy Picture of the Day**/
    var apod_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=[My Key]"
    var apod_img_urls = [];
    var curr_moment = moment();
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var appended_url = apod_url + "&date=" + curr_moment.subtract(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        request(appended_url, function(error, reponse, body) {
            if(!error && reponse.statusCode == 200) {
                var img_json = JSON.parse(body);
                if(img_json.media_type == "image") {
                    var apod_promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                        resolve(img_json.hdurl);
                    });
                    apod_img_urls.push(apod_promise);
                }
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
    /**************************************************/

    var url = "https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch?next=20&mode=verbose";
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
       if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           var data = JSON.parse(body);
           res.render("index", {data: data, apod_img_urls: apod_img_urls});
       } else {
           console.log(error);
       }
    });
});
```

Here is an EJS snippet

```
<% apod_img_urls.forEach(function(promise, index) { %>
    <div class="carousel-item <%= (index == 0 ? 'active' : '') %>">
        <div class="w-100 home-image" style="background-image: url('<%= promise.then(function(url) {return url}); %>')"></div>
    </div>
<% }); %>
```

When I check in the source it shows that the background image urls for the divs are [object Promise]. The way I have it, no images show up. Also the number of divs displayed (i.e. the number of images I should have) is variable; sometimes it's 5, sometimes it's 3, and other times it's none. Could my problem be that I'm rendering the page inside of another request? Also how can I get the actual image URL to show up in the EJS file?

Comment: if you want to use promisified "requests": easily, then use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) - of course, you'll need to know how to use promises too - as it is, you are creating the promise in the asynchronous callback - which is too late

Comment: Would I need to change a lot if i use request-promise?

Comment: Not really, but hang on, will post an answer without request-promise

Comment: Actually, request-promise is possibly overkill anyway for the code shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the promise too late, inside the asynchronous callback to reequest - fairly simple reorganisation of code required

Once all the promises are in an array, you then need to wait for them to complete, using Promise.all

```
app.get("/index", function(req, res) {
    /**Requesting NASA's Astronomy Picture of the Day**/
    var apod_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=[My Key]"
    var promises = [];
    var curr_moment = moment();
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var appended_url = apod_url + "&date=" + curr_moment.subtract(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request(appended_url, function(error, reponse, body) {
                if(!error && reponse.statusCode == 200) {
                    var img_json = JSON.parse(body);
                    resolve(img_json.hdurl);
                } else {
                    reject(error);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }));
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(apod_img_urls => {
        var url = "https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch?next=20&mode=verbose";
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
           if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
               var data = JSON.parse(body);
               res.render("index", {data, apod_img_urls});
           } else {
               console.log(error);
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Rather than using request-promise and all the cruft it requires, you can always make your own promisified `request` function, and in this case, it rejects if status is anything other than `200`

```
const requestP = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => request(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        reject({error, response, body});
    } else if (resonse.statusCode != 200) {
        reject(resonse.statusCode);
    } else {
        resolve({response, body});
    }
}));
```

now, your code can be written as:

```
app.get("/index", function(req, res) {
    /**Requesting NASA's Astronomy Picture of the Day**/
    const apod_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=[My Key]"
    const curr_moment = moment();
    Promise.all(Array.from({length:10}, (_, i) => {
        const appended_url = apod_url + "&date=" + curr_moment.subtract(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        return requestP(appended_url).then(({response, body}) => JSON.parse(body).hdurl);
    })).then(apod_img_urls => {
        const url = "https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch?next=20&mode=verbose";
        return requestP(url).then(({response, body}) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(body);
            return res.render("index", {data, apod_img_urls});
        });
    });
});
```

Note: there's a lot of ES2015+ going on in there

Comment: Thank you this worked. I knew it had to be an organization thing. There is one problem with the apod_img_urls; for some reason the final url is undefined. Is there a common solution to this? EDIT: Turns out the url is actually undefined so I'm guessing it's a problem with the API>

Answer (score 1):

If you use a promise-returning request library like `request-promise` then you can do something like:

```
app.get("/index", function(req, res) {
    var apod_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=[My Key]"
    var curr_moment = moment();
    var urls = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        urls[i] = apod_url + "&date=" + curr_moment.subtract(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    }
    Promise.all(urls.map(url => rp({ url, json: true})).then((results) => {
      // here you have all results with JSON already parsed for you
      // ...
    }).catch((err) => {
      // handle error
      // make sure to return response to client
      // ...
    });
    // ...
});
```

If you want to work with promises then use a promise-returning module like `request-promise` or `axios` instead of the standard `request`, see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Or, alternatively, use `bluebird.promisify` or built-in `util.primisify` (since 8.0) to promisify the `request` module, see:

- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html
- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html

For more options of promisifying `request` see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait

Then, when you have a promise-returning request library, make an array of URLs however you want, then map that array with the request functions, like this:

```
let rp = require('request-promise');
let urls = ['http://...', 'http://...'];
let promises = urls.map(rp);
```

and then use `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to finish, while being done concurrently:

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

or, if you're using async/await, then:

```
try {
  let x = await Promise.all(promises);
  ...
} catch (err) {
  ...
}
```

Many of modules like `axios` or `request-promise-json` or `request-promise` will parse JSON for you if you run it correctly, see:

- https://github.com/request/request-promise#get-something-from-a-json-rest-api

Avoid parsing JSON yourself but if you do then **always** put `JSON.parse()` inside of `try/catch` (or use my little [`tryjson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryjson) module) - see those answers to know why:

- [Calling a JSON API with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826384/calling-a-json-api-with-node-js/39612292#39612292)
- [Reading requests body Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394650/reading-requests-body-nodejs/44394849#44394849)
- [Node JS ignores undefined check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912653/node-js-ignores-undefined-check/40912917#40912917)